# Combining Results into a single variable

Tags: php, loops

I have a foreach loop in my php script that exports the results I need.

I would like to have these result be combine into one variable rather than printing each result for me. I don't even know the function of what I'm trying to do is called,

but I know its goes something like this:

```
   if($mins) {
      $ips .= $item++;
   } else {
      $has .= $item++;
   }
```

Therefore, I want to print out all the $items with $mins like this:

```
"$item $item $item $item $item"
```

I want $ips to equal/hold the entire `"$item $item $item $item $item"` not just singular.

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you have 2 variables and you want to combine them in one variable
like combining them into an array?

Comment: Your question is very vague. But perhaps look up arrays.

Comment: I see where you're going with that code, and you've certainly got your mind going in the right direction, but I think you should probably do a bit more research on how variables, arrays, for loops, and foreach loops work in PHP, in that order.

Comment: $item is my ips i want to print out in a row when echo'ing $ips...

Comment: @thevoipman could you please give an example...

Comment: @Ibrahim.I just edited my question

Comment: @thevoipman still so vague...
you're not making your self clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly you can do this with

```
$ips = null;
$has = null;
foreach ( (array) $Arr AS $key => $val){
if ($mins){
    $ips .= $key;
}
    $has .= $key;
}
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Answer changed completely due to now clearer question)

Add the result to the relevant array:

```
if($mins) {
   $ips[]=$item;      
} else {
   $has[]=$item;  
}
```

Print the results with explode:

```
echo ("ips: ".explode(" ",$ips)."\n");
echo ("has: ".explode(" ",$has));
```

First parameter of explode() function is a string that will be inserted between the elements of the second param array, a space in this case.

Comment: `$sum_of_results+=$single_result;` like like this one, this is the one I've been missing on top of my head